# Notification of subfolders inside inbox in outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I created a subfolder inside inbox folder and created a rule to move some of the emails to this folder. I am not getting any notification when mails are arriving to this subfolder.

I haven't been able to find a way to setup alert on this subfolder. Is there some way I can setup the alert?

Comment: Modify the rule you created to move the mail and add an additional action for alerts.

Comment: There is no such option in outlook 2016.

Comment: Click advanced options. They’re all there.

Comment: Microsoft office 365 ProPlus works

Comment: @Appleoddity there is no 'advanced options'... https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15261525/128948672-ee9ad0e5-36f9-4bd8-8940-06536bfd459c.png

Comment: @ragurney you’re showing what appears to be a screenshot of options you see when you right click a message. This entire post is about outlook rules. The options are in the “Manage Rules & Alerts” section.

Comment: No, this is the UI for the rules in the most recent version of Outlook. Here's an expanded version:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15261525/129087967-fc69dcb3-371a-4839-abda-2e4c3ee1d659.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15261525/129088209-6f8c893d-c20d-4c8b-b38d-912e81962fe9.png

I think the only workaround that exists is to choose the 'Copy to' action as opposed to the 'Move to' to keep a copy of the email in the Inbox folder, which allows a notification to be shown.

Answer (score 15):

In the last version of Outlook (2016/365), it's hidden under the 'Rules' button in the ribbon:

Select 'edit rules', and select the protocol your e-mail account uses under 'Client rules'. There you can just click the + icon and add a rule for every subdirectory as follows:

- Rule name: Anything
- When a new message arrives: all messages
- Execute the following action: Play Sound (or Show Notification)

Click 'OK' and repeat this for every subdirectory you want to receive a notification for.

Comment: It looks like this is outdated. There is no longer a 'play sound' or 'show notification' option for rules. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Outlook new mail notification only works for emails in Inbox folder. If you want Outlook to show alerts for emails moved to subfolders, add the following action in the inbox rule you used to move the emails.

[image]

Comment: I don't see that option in outlook 2016

Comment: In Outlook, under Home tab on the ribbon, click Rules -> Manage Rules & Alerts. In the opened dialog which titled 'Rules and Alerts', double click the rule you created to move emails to subfolder, click Next to the "Which contition(s) do you want to check?" step, scroll to the bottom. The 'display a Desktop Alert' option should be the second from the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who were struggling to find the "display a Desktop Alert" setting, it's on the next page of the dialog.

In the Rules wizard, click the Next button so that it says "Step 1: What do you want to do with the message?"